# Weblogic server -Fail to convert to internal representation: weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Blob_oracle_sql_BLOB@3

Tags: java, oracle, blob, weblogic11g

While passing a file in the form of a blob to an Oracle database- I'm getting this error in Weblogic. This same code works fine in Tomcat server:

```
    Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation: 
    weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Blob_oracle_sql_BLOB@3
    &#59; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []&#59; SQL state [99999]&#59; error code [17059]&#59; 
    Fail to convert to internal representation: weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Blob_oracle_sql_BLOB@3&#59; 
    nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation: 
    weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Blob_oracle_sql_BLOB@3
```

Please help me sort this.

Answer (score 3):

Weblogic uses Weblogic Wrapper objects by default to wrap Array, Blob, Clob, Nclob and some other types.

You can turn off this setting per DataSource. Setting is located in Weblogic Administration Console: DataSource->Configuration->Connection Pool->Advanced->Wrap Data Types (if you turn this off, it should resolve your problem).

Note that after disabling, the changes will take effect after redeployment of an application / server restart.